# Meteor react validation package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Anybody can suggest Meteor react form validation package or custom validation code which suitable for a component. I just need solution like jquery validate which work with meteor and react.

Comment: Do you mean form validation?

Comment: yes.  form validation in react for Meteor js

Comment: For me, using html5 attribute [pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) is enough for validating input format. Further validation regarding application logic should be took care of by code

Comment: Yes. Kind of code i am looking for. HTML pattern cannot be solution for this. This solution should be like jquery validate. But jquery validate not working with Meteor react template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used react-validation-mixin package and its good.

> https://github.com/jurassix/react-validation-mixin

Example -: http://jurassix.github.io/react-validation-mixin/

Also, I have used `joi-browser` instead of `joi` for es6 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it yet, but this looks good: https://github.com/vazco/uniforms

It works with https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema which seems to be the defacto standard validation library for Meteor.